# t:fileInputUpload null source when uploading file

Tags: exception, jsf, upload, null, tomahawk

I'm using tomahawk (1.1.11) and Mojarra (2.1.4) to develop a JSF app. When I upload small files (kb) it works fine, but when I upload files of about 160Mb it sends an error **null source**.

Here's my code so far:

```
    <h:form id="menuForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:outputLabel for="option" value="Acciones disponibles: " />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="option"
                         value="#{uploadFile.option}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione una opción..." itemValue="null" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{uploadFile.options}" />
            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <h:panelGrid id="dataLoad" columns ="3" 
                     rendered="#{uploadFile.option == 'Agregar información (sin validación).' ||
                                 uploadFile.option == 'Cargar información completa (con validación).' || 
                                 uploadFile.option == 'Cargar solo información errónea (con validación).'}">
            <h:outputLabel for="upfile" value="Archivo: " />
            <t:inputFileUpload id="upfile" 
                               value="#{uploadFile.upFile}" />
            <h:panelGroup/>
            <h:panelGroup/>
            <h:commandButton value="Continuar"
                             onclick="return confirmation()"
                             action="#{uploadFile.upload}" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid id="dataValidate" columns="3"
                     rendered="#{uploadFile.option == 'Validar información actual.'}">
            <h:commandButton value=" Validar " action="#{uploadFile.validate()}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid id="listFiles" columns="3"
                     rendered="#{uploadFile.option == 'Visualizar todos los archivos.'}">
            <t:tree2 id="tree" value="#{listFiles.treeRoot}"
                     var="node" varNodeToggler="t" 
                     clientSideToggle="false">
                <f:facet name="folder">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <t:graphicImage value="images/folderOpen.png"
                                        rendered="#{t.nodeExpanded}"
                                        border="0" />
                        <t:graphicImage value="images/folderClose.png"
                                        rendered="#{!t.nodeExpanded}"
                                        border="0" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{node.description}"
                                      styleClass="nodeFolder" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="file">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:commandLink immediate="true"
                                       action="#{listFiles.download(node.identifier)}">
                            <t:graphicImage value="images/file.png" border="0" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{node.description}" />
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </f:facet>
            </t:tree2>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

and actually I need to upload files larger than that, even up to 2 Gb. Any advise?

**UPDATE**

Here's the full stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
at java.util.EventObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:71)
at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:73)
at javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent.<init>(PostRestoreStateEvent.java:73)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:271)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:257)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:269)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1773)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**UPDATE**

I will also put the `web.xml` file, maybe I'm missing some configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_EXTENSIONS_FILTER</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
            <param-value>5g</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadThresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>500m</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>/faces/*</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace in your question.

Comment: I have added also the web.xml config, maybe I'm missing some configuration of tomahawk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ! I found the cause of the problem, but I'm no really sure what was going on, so I would like if someone can help me out with this.

First, the problem was with the **web.xml** file. At the very end I had something like

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>/faces/*</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

So I delete it from the web.xml and it upload the file without any problems! I think, the server was confused with this `` `filter-mapping `` and the `servlet-mapping`. I hope someone with more experience help me (and all people reading this question) clear this thing out.

Comment: On the other hand, I was able to upload files in the order of Mb, but I need to upload a file of about 3.86 Gb. I tried uploading large files but it does not send any error / exception.

Comment: The `<servlet-name>` should point to the `<servlet-name>` of the `FacesServlet`, not represent an URL pattern. You already have the proper one, so indeed remove that wrong entry.

Answer (score 0):

Rabbit you can rip out the FileUploadBase file from apache commons fileupload jar that you are using

and set the max file and request size limits in that if you wish. This is what i did to overcome size limits after searching for any config items to customise the limit above apaches File Upload 1.2.1  100mb limit that it was imposing on me.

you can get src off http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload//index.html

just modify source file recompile and overwrite existing class file in you fileupload jar

make sure you get the source zip that corresponds exactly to the version of file upload you are using otherwise you might get problems